# How to get the total value at the end of a particular column for the shown values in the report only?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report , there are few columns in my report whose calculations are done in the report, also i need to display the total value of the calculated column ex:

```
ID||Name||Value||Positive||Negative

1||  ABC||200  || 200    || 0

2||  BCD||300  || 300    || 0

3||  EFG||-500 ||0       ||-500

4||  HIJ||-200 || 0      ||-200

---------------------------------
TOTAL          ||500     ||-700
```

I have achieved the how to show positive and negative values separately by using reportItems and IIF condition but I the total of these columns also.

Can Anyone help me

Comment: `=SUM(Fields!Positive.Value)`

Comment: I tried but it is still not working...

Comment: I am Calculating the "Value" in report and applying =IIF(ReportItems!Value.Value>0,ReportItems!Value.Value,0) in Positive Column =IIF(ReportItems!Value.Value<0,ReportItems!Value.Value,0) for Negative Column. Now I want Positive and Negative Columns Total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use ReportItems!Value.   Use the field of your dataset that populates the Value column.   And do:

Positive:  SUM(IIF(Fields!ValueField.Value>0,Fields!ValueField.Value,0))

Negative:  Same only <0.

Replace "ValueField" with whatever field in your dataset is populating the Value column.  If it's a combination of fields, put that whole combination in place of the Fields!ValueField.Value